# Why can't i access my s3 objects in amplify flutter?

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, access-denied

[Message displayed on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Hk2.png)

Function to get the S3 URL

```
Future<String> getUrlS3(String UploadKey) async {
    try {
      GetUrlResult result =
      await Amplify.Storage.getUrl(key: UploadKey);
      return(result.url);
    } on StorageException catch (e) {
      return(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Function to get url

```
Future<void> cet() async {
    String store = await S3Helper.getUrlS3('cover807c3f99-2bcb-44e3-be80-4899ea2355d8Attac');
    print(store);
  }
```

When I click on the link I get the access denied page.
The only way i can see the Objects are if i make the specific object public, also i am logged in via Auth Cognito so i should have the permissions to view them

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass accesslevel option to your getUrlS3.
something like this

```
S3DownloadFileOptions options = S3UploadFileOptions(
  accessLevel: StorageAccessLevel.protected,
  metadata: metadata,
);
```